# Track on blur for all child inputs inside formgroup directive

Tags: angular, directive, viewchild

I have a forgroup wit a bunch of input fields. I would like to set up an onblur event for all of the input fields, to send an event to external analytics. Instead of tagging every single input field with an onblur even, I want to set it on the formgroup.
I am able to loop over the elements using the viewchildren query, but I want this functionality to be reusable, so I was thinking of creating a directive.

I created a directive and set it on the formgroup, but apparently it is not possible to query ViewChildren using a directive.

Is there a way to create a directive that queries all input fields, and then adds n onblur listener to them ?

Comment: I think it's fine to create one directive and put it on each formControl

Comment: Not quite sure if thats working but I think you can inject an `ElementRef` in the constructor of your directive which referes to the applied element, in your case the form(group). You could maybe use that for further query-selection of input fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel],[formControl],formControlName',
  exportAs: 'child'
})
export class BlurDirective {
  @HostListener('blur')_(){
    const value=this.control?this.control.value:null;
    const id=this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')
    console.log(id,value)
  }
  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef, 
              @Optional() @Self() private control:NgControl){}
}
```

makes the "trick"

Answer (score 0):

From your issue description, I think if you just want to add `onBlur` event so that you can capture any user input and send that to an external analytics.

I would suggest another approach.
You probably can subscribe to `formGroup's` `valueChanges` event, and send the data to analytics service with each change or input.

```
this.yourForm.valueChanges.subscribe(formField => {
    // TODO call external analytics service
})
```

Comment: This would mean custom code in every component. I was looking for a directive so I can share this code over input fields I want to tag