# Angular: Detect changes for each event on a page (component)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, recursion, onchange

I am developing an application in Angular 10. I have created a **recursive component**, which shows dynamic "forms" containing different input fields (checkbox, radio buttons, text input, etc ..).
This is a small example of the HTML code of `my-component`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="valueChosen" name="field" id="field">
        <option *ngFor="let data of datas" [ngValue]="data.code">{{data.text}}</option>

        <div>
              <my-component [datas] = "data">
              </my-component>    
        </div>
</select>
```

The real code is much longer but I hope to give the idea: The component itself is used by passing it in input a sub-part of the original data. It means that since it is not a "fixed form" (but it is dynamically created at each use) I cannot associate every single input to a specific element in the `component.ts` file.
I would like a system that allows me to detect (using something similar to the watch in AngularJS) every single click / check / insertion of text that the user makes in this dynamic form.
Unfortunately I cannot use Reactive Forms, as they assume a link between `component.ts` and `component.html`.

Comment: you can create a directive that work about all the [(ngModel)], e.g. in this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491037/track-on-blur-for-all-child-inputs-inside-formgroup-directive/66492829#66492829 you has a directive that "listen" all the blur -you can use `@HostListener('input')`-

Answer (score 0):

If it was a dynamic form then use Angular's Reactive forms and take advantage of FormArray to add and remove form controls dynamically. Then subscribe to form's valueChanges for Data change events. This will also allow you to add or clear form validators if needed.

Additionally you can add a directive with HostListeners on Form for all the other events [Event Bubbling will help you] like touch, click etc.